# Create Flux from messages on SQS queue

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to create a `Flux` from incoming messages received from a queue.

For instance, if I'm using Amazon SQS how do I achieve to write the following code:

```
Flux<String> messages = connectionToSQS.receiveFromQueue(queueName);
```

messages.map(s -> log.info("message: {}", s).subscribe();

After experimentation, I found the following issues:

- How do I keep requesting messages from the queue (loop forever)?  Do I create one thread that has a loop that keeps on requesting from the queue?
- How do I make the `Flux` cold?  I don't want to request messages from SQS unless the consumer asks for it.  This allows me to use backpressure.

First pass over this problem yielded something like the following code as per Reactor documentation:

```
Flux<String> bridge = Flux.create(sink -> {
    myEventProcessor.register(new MyEventListener<String>() { 
        public void onDataChunk(List<String> chunk) {
            for(String s : chunk) {
                sink.next(s); 
            }
        }

        public void processComplete() {
            sink.complete(); 
        }
    });
});
```

The idea being to create a single thread that keeps on requesting for messages in a loop and then using an observer pattern like above to do a `next()` on each message received.

Comment: Typically sqs queue readers loop on some condition.   In your case you might loop until no messages are available and then break out of the loop.  You'll probably want to pull as many messages as you can process in a reasonable time frame to reduce cost and latency.  You'll also want to set the max wait to be small if you'd prefer ending the loop to waiting for late arriving messages.   Finally,  don't forget to delete the messages once you've proceeded them.